# Using Python to identify if two words contain the same letter

Tags: python-3.x, loops, anagram

Problem to solve:

> Write a function that will find all the anagrams of a word from a list. You will be given two inputs a word and an array with words. You should return an array of all the anagrams or an empty array if there are none.

Solution Tested:

```
a = ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']
b = ['abab']
listA = []
sorted_defaultword = sorted(b[0])
print (sorted_defaultword)
for i in range (len(a)):
    #print(a[i])
    sorted_word = sorted(a[i])
    #print (sorted_word)
    if (sorted_word == sorted_defaultword):
        listA.append(a[i])
print (listA)
```

Test Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
['aabb', 'bbaa']
```

Using the test, I then tried to write my function but apparently it will not work. Can someone please suggest why:

```
def anagrams(word, words):
    
    sorted_defaultword = sorted(word[0])
    anagram_List = []
    
    for i in range (len(words)):
        sorted_word = sorted(words[i])
        if (sorted_word == sorted_defaultword):
            anagram_List.append(words[i])
    return anagram_List
```

Why is this failing when I put it in a function?

Comment: the first argument of the function, 'word', what are you passing to it? Just the word or a list containing exactly one word? Are you passing b,  `b = ['abab']` or `b = 'abab'`

Comment: Test.assert_equals(anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']), ['aabb', 'bbaa']). Here is a sample test so I think it is a list containing exactly one word

Comment: umm no, it is not a list. It is just a string, while your function expects a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong arguments to the function.

`Test.assert_equals(anagrams('abba', ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']), ['aabb', 'bbaa']`
here you are passing the first parameter as a string. while the function expects a list.
Change your code to:
`Test.assert_equals(anagrams(['abba'], ['aabb', 'abcd', 'bbaa', 'dada']), ['aabb', 'bbaa']`

note that I have just passed 'abba' in a list, because your function expects it to be a list.

If you want to use your previous code, from your function change this line `sorted_defaultword = sorted(word[0])` to `sorted_defaultword = sorted(word)`

And this should do the job...